# Get array from response in swift

Tags: ios, swift

i'm trying to get response in my model object, but facing an issue that it is showing me only first item of response, this is my code,

```
func getUserBalanceAPI()
{

    APIService.getUserBalance{ (responseObject) in
        if (responseObject?.status)! {
            self.balanceArray.removeAll()

             let user = UserCompleteBalance(JSON: (responseObject?.data as! [[String : Any]]).first!)
            self.balanceArray.append(user!)

            //Reload Collection View
            self.currencyCVC.reloadData()
        }
        else if !(responseObject?.status)! {
            Utilities.showBar(text: responseObject?.errorObject?.message)
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get all the items in an array? This is my response,

```
"responseBody": {
    "data": [
        {
            "auction_deposit": 4083.63,
            "currencyCode": "USD",
            "userCurrencyId": 1,
            "availableBalance": 64555.1,
            "currentBalance": 68638.73
        },
        {
            "auction_deposit": 0.0,
            "currencyCode": "AED",
            "userCurrencyId": 2,
            "availableBalance": 198000.0,
            "currentBalance": 198000.0
        },
        {
            "auction_deposit": 0.0,
            "currencyCode": "EUR",
            "userCurrencyId": 3,
            "availableBalance": 50000.0,
            "currentBalance": 50000.0
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my model class,

```
class UserCompleteBalance : Mappable {

var auctionDeposit : Int?
var availableBalance : Int?
var currencyCode : Int?
var currentBalance : Int?
var userCurrencyId : Int?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {

    auctionDeposit <- map["auction_deposit"]
    currencyCode <- map["currencyCode"]
    userCurrencyId <- map["userCurrencyId"]
    availableBalance <- map["availableBalance"]
    currentBalance <- map["currentBalance"]

}
}
```

Now i want to store all the response in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to the fact that you are getting only the first dictionary on the dictionary array, so you need to loop over your dictionary array to convert each of them on `UserCompleteBalance` model

## Updated

***You need to use [weak self] and strongSelf inside closure to avoid retain cycles***

**try with this code**

```
func getUserBalanceAPI()
{

    APIService.getUserBalance{ [weak self] (responseObject) in
       guard let strongSelf = self else {
           return 
       }

        if (responseObject?.status)! {
            strongSelf.balanceArray.removeAll()
            
             if let usersDataArray = responseObject?.data as? [[String : Any]] {
                for userData in usersDataArray {
                   strongSelf.balanceArray.append(UserCompleteBalance(JSON:userData))
                }
             }

            //Reload Collection View
            strongSelf.currencyCVC.reloadData()
        }
        else if !(responseObject?.status)! {
            Utilities.showBar(text: responseObject?.errorObject?.message)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this is perfect on, got it resolved thanks a lot. @Reinier Melian

Comment: Your welcome, @Hamza check my update about retain cycle, is important to avoid those before facing the real issue, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

`let user = UserCompleteBalance(JSON: (responseObject?.data as! [[String : Any]]).first!)
self.balanceArray.append(user!)`

Above lines should be in a loop through all objects in `responseObject.data`

Your `getUserBalanceAPI` functions should be

```
APIService.getUserBalance{ (responseObject) in
    if (responseObject?.status)! {
        self.balanceArray.removeAll()

        if let jsonObjects = responseObject?.data as? [[String : Any]] {
           for jsonObject in jsonObjects {
               if let user = UserCompleteBalance(JSON: jsonObject) {
                   self.balanceArray.append(user)
               }
           }
        }
        //Reload Collection View
        self.currencyCVC.reloadData()
    } else if !(responseObject?.status)! {
        Utilities.showBar(text: responseObject?.errorObject?.message)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i'm trying to loop through it like this,
for item in responseObject?.data
                {
                    
                }
but it is showing me error, Type 'AnyObject?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence' . @jacob

Comment: Let's show my your class `UserCompleteBalance`. 
BTW, i dont see any loop in your code above. @Hamza

Comment: check my question i have updated with my model class and loop is in my comment. @jacob

Comment: An accepted answer or upvote will be a great motivation for me. Thanks. @Hamza